# JAVA 8 (JDK) version for RHEL7 (IBM linuxone Community cloud)

Tags: java, rhel

I am trying to install Java 8 or 9 on the RHEL. I have tried the 8 and 9 JDK for linux_64bit rpm from oracle website. It complains : the binary is not compatible for the architecture.

**OS version and architecture details:**
Linux ds1 3.10.0-327.36.2.el7.s390x #1 SMP Tue Sep 27 16:04:40 EDT 2016 s390x s390x s390x GNU/Linux

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)

Please advise which JDK version must i use

Comment: Found the JDK for the IBM Z series linux system. developer.ibm.com/javasdk/downloads/sdk8 Filename: ibm-java-s390x-sdk-8.0-5.0.bin

Answer (score 0):

The OpenJDK 8 package is called `java-1.8.0-openjdk`.  The JDK is in package `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`.  Red Hat ships OpenJDK builds for s390x, so they should be available for the indicated system, too.  IBM probably provides a custom JRE/JDK for s390x, too, but I have never used any of those.